# jQuery Easing and Animation with CSS3 Styles

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation

I have a loop rotation animation going from '-1deg' to '1deg' and its a very choppy as im just changing the css, not animating.. Because if im correct you currently cannot animate rotation?

Is there any way I can use easing or am I wrong about animating css rotations?

```
jQuery('.foo').css('transform','rotate(-1deg)');
jQuery('.foo').css('transform','rotate(1deg)');
```

**Thanks**

Comment: You can animate rotation in CSS

Answer (score 1):

Use two classes. Before and after. Add the after to the before and then use a transition e.g.

```
.before{
color: blue;
}

.after{
color: red;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Then on the element before:

```
<element class="before"></element>
```

The element after:

```
<element class="before after"></element>
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to offer a plugin solution, but this one is very neat: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

The syntax is identical to animate, eg:

```
$('.box').transition({ rotate: '45deg' }, 1000, 'ease-in');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `@keyframes` animation With css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

You can see an example here **http://jsfiddle.net/NBS7p/6/**.

The compatibility http://caniuse.com/css-animation

And more tips about `@keyframes` http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

Try with CSS `animation`:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sway {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    }
}

.foo {
    -webkit-animation: sway 500ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SMPKd/1/